# How to interpret draftsman plot

Tags: scatterplot, exploratory-data-analysis

I've conduct some draftsman plot to find the correlation between variables.

And I got this kind of result.
[image]

But I don't understand how to interpret the data.
What is the different between the color? And also the number?

Very appreciate if anyone could give some clue for this

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. See the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) for `corrplot` package: "Positive correlations are displayed in blue and negative correlations in red color. Color intensity and the size of the circle are proportional to the correlation coefficients."

Comment: Thank you @T.E.G. It does helped me and also the link.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, the correlation summarizes the strength of linear relationship between two variables. It ranges from -1 (perfect negative correlation) to 1 (perfect positive correlation). Draftsman balls use size to represent magnitude (0 to 1) and color to represent direction (blue is positive, peach is negative).

This plot is redundant, in my mind, having so few features. You can just look at the correlation values in the lower diagonal to glean all the salient details. The draftsman plot, or a heatmap, could be suitable if you had 20 or more features.